# Python 3.6.5 Pandas Excel - Find tabular data in excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to extract only the tabular data from some excel books with multiple sheets that do not conform to any standard layout.  I could write some code that loops over the rows and columns to find a table (find 2 or more contiguous cells/rows) but was hoping there may be a better way. I am implementing this in Python (v3.6.5) Pandas.

Sample scenarios:

Tabular data randomly placed in sheet - I want to extract only the 'Col' and 'Row' data.

A   B   C   D   E
blank   blank   blank   blank   blank
blank   blank   blank   blank   blank
blank   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
blank   Row1    Row1    Row1    Row1
blank   Row2    Row2    Row2    Row2
blank   Row3    Row3    Row3    Row3
blank   Row4    Row4    Row4    Row4
blank   Row5    Row5    Row5    Row5
blank   Row6    Row6    Row6    Row6
blank   Row7    Row7    Row7    Row7
blank   Row8    Row8    Row8    Row8

Tabular data starts at rows 3-6 - I want to extract only the 'Col' and 'Row' data.

A   B   C   D   E
blank
blank
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Row1    Row1    Row1    Row1
Row2    Row2    Row2    Row2
Row3    Row3    Row3    Row3
Row4    Row4    Row4    Row4
Row5    Row5    Row5    Row5
Row6    Row6    Row6    Row6
Row7    Row7    Row7    Row7
Row8    Row8    Row8    Row8

Tabular data starts after merged cells- I want to step over the merged cells and extract only the 'Col' and 'Row' data.

A   B   C   D   E
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
data in merged cells (A thru D)
data in merged cells (A thru D)
Row1    Row1    Row1    Row1
Row2    Row2    Row2    Row2
Row3    Row3    Row3    Row3
Row4    Row4    Row4    Row4
Row5    Row5    Row5    Row5
Row6    Row6    Row6    Row6
Row7    Row7    Row7    Row7
Row8    Row8    Row8    Row8

A   B   C   D   E
    some    data
    some    data
    some    data
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Row1    Row1    Row1    Row1
Row2    Row2    Row2    Row2
Row3    Row3    Row3    Row3
Row4    Row4    Row4    Row4
Row5    Row5    Row5    Row5
Row6    Row6    Row6    Row6
Row7    Row7    Row7    Row7
Row8    Row8    Row8    Row8

**EDIT**
This is what I have do far:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
directory = '[path]'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xlsm") or filename.endswith(".xls"):
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
        # print xl.sheet_names
        sheets = xl.sheet_names
        print()
        print(filename)
        for sheet in sheets:
            df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet)
            #TO DO: extract tabular data from df
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show a minimal code (even if it doesn't work)?

Comment: sure, thanks ma3oun

Comment: please provide a 'mcve': https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem on my own.  thanks